# Changing the network name?

Tags: docker-compose

I see I can change the project name with the `--project-name` parameter or by setting the `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable, and that the project name goes into creation of the network containers are added to e.g. `myproject_default` but is there no way of changing the network name?

suppose I just wanted to call it `myproject` instead of `myproject_default`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not as the time I write this answer.

You can set your network name in docker-compose file by using the [name option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#name-1), which was added in version 3.5 file format.

```
version: '3.5'
networks:
  network1:
    name: my-app-net
```

Answer (score 1):

**In short**, you can set default network name using the [name option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#name-1) like this:

```
version: '3.5'

networks:
  default:
    name: my-app-net
```

---

**Detailed**:

If you name your custom network then you should use it in your services, such as:

```
services:

  proxy:
    build: ./proxy
    networks:
      - my-app-net
```

**To skip this excess step** you should customize your default network as described above (not some custom `network1` as @quinn-wynn suggest).